# Regex Procedure Parameters : Oracle

Tags: regex, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I'm trying to create a dinamic insert which works for any database table.
The insert procedure receive 2 parameters: table name and table_data:

`EXECUTE P_INSERTS('TABLE_NAME','''ONE_STRING'',''1234''');`

On the procedure, the regex is:

`DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE( LIST => REGEXP_REPLACE(TABLE_DATA,'(^|,)|($|'')|(^|'')','\1X'), TABLEN => L_COUNT, TAB => L_ARRAY);`

I need to get an array like:
data1
data2
data3

I'm getting the following error: ORA-01756: Quoted String Not Properly Terminated.
Can you guys help in with the regex?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the source code of the `p_inserts` procedure? The literals used in the snippets shown are ok ( checked with [this sqlfiddle](https://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f3f25/1)).

Comment: The code is long to post as a comment, but yes, the result is 'X'ONE_STRINGX,X X1234XX' despite i was trying to get 'ONE_STRING,123'. The problem is in the regex, but i don't really know how to solve it.